# C# Waiting for an action in a parallel thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# form application to send CAN messages.

At the start, I start a thread which monitors incoming messages, and displays them on a `DataGridView`.

Currently the app is set so that the user can send a CAN message one at time, and view its response.
All this works fine, and reliably.

Phase 2 of my application requires me to send a full list of CAN messages automatically.
For this I need to send a CAN message, and wait for its response, and then send the next.

How can I monitor the receive thread, and halt my send function long enough for the response to be received?

As the send message is not in a separate thread, `Thread.Sleep(n)` halts the entire program.

Comment: Have you read about aync/await in C# 5, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how you send messages...  e.g. if it's a call to something like `SendMyMessage`, then just send the next after that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public AsynchronousCommand Send;

    public DataViewModel()
    {
        Send = new AsynchronousCommand(() =>
        {
            SendData();
        });
    }

    private void SendData()
    {
    }
}

public class SomewhereInForm
{
    private DataViewModel dataViewModel = new DataViewModel();

    public SomewhereInForm()
    {
        dataViewModel.Send.Executed += SendOnExecuted;
    }

    private void SendOnExecuted(object sender, CommandEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    private void DoSome()
    {
        dataViewModel.Send.DoExecute(new int());
    }
}
```

It's example with 1 command. You can put commands in List, whatever.

If you don't want build your own library witch commands, use this: [Commands in MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM)